# Error while compiling ffmpeg during make

Tags: 10.10, command-line, compiling, ffmpeg

I want to install ffmpeg on ubuntu. and following this article http://pasindudps.blogspot.com/2010/12/compiling-ffmpeg-in-ubuntu-1010.html but when m doing make after config

```
Then go to the ffmpeg folder.
cd ffmpeg
Start the installation
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc \
--enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb \
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis \
--enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab
make
```

giving this error

```
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_norm_shift'
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_lps_range'
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_norm_shift'
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_mlps_state'
/home/reach121/ffmpeg/libavcodec/x86/cabac.h:93: undefined reference to `ff_h264_norm_shift'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [ffmpeg_g] Error 1
```

Please suggest why this error is coming and what to do to solve this problem

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't install the ffmpeg version from the official Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: i dont know how to install from official repository , and m doing this because encoding to mp3 file was not working in previous instalation so reinstalling again with above article

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using (probably 10.10 as you are using a guide for that version)

Comment: Could you post your full log? Something wasn't compiled well, that's why it now complains about undefined referenes.

Comment: Yeah right its 10.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu version of ffmpeg comes without support for restricted formats like MP3, but you can fix that by installing packages that include that support. So to fix your initial problem:

1. Purge the existing installation of ffmpeg (if any):

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge ffmpeg
   ```
2. Install ffmpeg:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
   ```
3. To install the restricted formats, you need to enable the *Multiverse* and *Universe* repositories. Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

   and uncomment the lines ending with `multiverse` and `universe`. If you don't have such lines, just append the following to the file:

   ```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates multiverse
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security multiverse

   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick universe
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick universe
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates universe
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-updates universe
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
   deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security universe
   ```

   Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> , <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +   <kbd>x</kbd>).

   Now update the package list by running:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install support for restricted formats like MP3:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-52
   ```

Now something like:

```
 ffmpeg -i in.wav out.mp3
```

should work.

Comment: pls see the error i got while doing step 4 in edited question

Comment: @htorque i am accessing it by putty ,it is on rackspace instance so i cant enable it by gui , i want to know the command for setting that

Comment: still the same error is coming ?  E: Package 'libavcodec-extra-52' has no installation candidate , when i pasted in source.list the six line already there with ending with universe , i appended your six line below them  and there was no line ending with  `multiverse `

Comment: Beware when overwriting the whole file. Rackspace may add their own repo (or not), you'd better just add the multiverse lines.

Comment: @RahulMehta I added the information to the answer (it turns out you also need the universe repository - my bad), please delete your comments on the answer so we can keep this question clean. Thanks. :-)